# Groovy Postbuild Script Jenkins - Kill Process

Tags: groovy, jenkins, kill

I'm trying to kill all ruby processes before starting a new one in a Groovy postbuild script in Jenkins. It looks like that:

```
def command_kill = "kill -9 `pidof ruby`"
def proc_kill = command_kill.execute()
proc_kill.waitFor()
```

which results in

> KILL: stderr: ERROR: garbage process ID "ruby`".

What's wrong here? This works in the Debian terminal on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
def procId = "pidof ruby".execute()
def killProc = "kill ${procId.in.text}".execute()
```